# Multiple memberships Webform and Paypal

Tags: webform-civicrm

I've set up a webform to create two memberships at a reduced rate vs two individual memberships.  I select two contacts, each has a membership.  The payment is associated with the first member.  There are options for 1, 2, or 3 years.  As an example, individual membership for 1 year is $15, and I want to register two people at the same postal address as members for $20.  Setting up the form everything looks fine, with some exceptions.  I can even use the feature to copy the postal address of the first member to the second member, cool.  One problem is that both members are given the option of membership type (1,2, or 3 yr).  In fact, what I want is the chosen term applied to both.  Only member one pays, and both get memberships.

Anyway, I fill out the form for both members and submit to PayPal standard.  I don't complete the payment.  I see a pending household membership for member 2 which presumably would show as completed if I actually paid.  But there is no payment for member 2, pending or otherwise.  Member 1 has no payment or membership record at all.

So, I thought I could probably work this all out if I was able to hook into the PayPal Instant payment notification (IPN).  I thought there would be some civiCRM hooks for this, but I don't see any.  So, I really need to know when the payment is completed and assign membership to both.

Answer (score 1):

> One problem is that both members are given the option of membership type (1,2, or 3 yr). In fact, what I want is the chosen term applied to both. Only member one pays, and both get memberships

I would try to tackle this via webform Conditionals, eg if the Memb Type for cid1 is 'not empty', hide Memb Type for cid2 or something similar

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using conferred memberships, where a membership extends to other contacts via relationships.  Webform can create the relationship between the contacts.

If you still need to go the IPN route, you'll want the [postIPNprocess hook](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postIPNProcess/).